# How to make boxes with measurment in pixel for various things on design?

Tags: windows-xp, productivity, portable

How to make boxes with measurement in pixel for various things on design ? transparent boxes on design with height and width.

Like this. round corner is not necessary. but when i draw boxes then size should be display like this. and i want to draw boxes for whole design at once then save pic with all transparent boxes.

Any trick in photoshop, fireworks, free online tool or any other free and portable utility for Windows XP?

[image]

Comment: closed as not computer related - I'm not talking about mobile apps

Answer (score 1):

[Inkscape](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscape/files/inkscape/0.47/Inkscape-0.47-3.exe/download) or another vector art application would allow you to create shapes and specify the size in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Is it about creating some sort of mask? If yes, use any vector graphical application to create it in black/white boxes, than export to some lossless format like bmp or tiff and import to photoshop as mask. You can set transporency layer to be created from mask. Your vector image should be as big as your target bitmap.

Comment: not only mask i need ruler software .along with masking and measurement.

Answer (score 0):

I found closet solution to my needs

http://www.pixelwindowapp.com/